# Can I return a templated container of different type?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming, template-templates

How can I create a function which behaves like this? I can't seem to declare the return type correctly.

```
template <typename C, typename T0, typename T1>
typename C<T1> 
convert_container(const C<T0>& container, T1 value) {
  C<T1> new_container;
  // Do some stuff...
  return new_container;
}

std::vector<int> vec0;
const auto& vec1 = convert_container(vec0, float(2.0f)); // Produce a vector of floats

std::list<int> lst0;
const auto& lst1 = convert_container(lst0, float(2.0f)); // Produce a list of floats
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135206/an-std-container-inside-a-template-method

I don't think the issue is just the return type, your template declarations look a little odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to use template template parameter:

- C++11:

  ```
  template <template<typename...> class C, typename T0, typename T1>
  C<T1> convert_container(const C<T0>& container, T1 value) {
    C<T1> new_container;
    // Do some stuff...
    return new_container;
  }
  ```
- C++03 (with allocator rebind):

  ```
  template <template<typename, typename> class C, typename T0, typename T1, typename Alloc>
  C<T1, typename Alloc::template rebind<T1>::other>
  convert_container(const C<T0, Alloc>& container, T1 value) {
    C<T1, typename Alloc::template rebind<T1>::other> new_container;
    // Do some stuff...
    return new_container;
  }
  ```
- C++03 (without rebind):

  ```
  template <template<typename, typename> class C, typename T0, typename T1, typename Alloc>
  C<T1, std::allocator<T1> > convert_container(const C<T0, Alloc>& container, T1 value) {
    C<T1, std::allocator<T1> > new_container;
    // Do some stuff...
    return new_container;
  }
  ```

Comment: Hmm is it possible to do without full C++11 support (ie VS2012)?

Comment: I guess you then have to replace `typename...` with the proper count of `typename`s. The classes you mentioned have more than one template parameter, they also have an allocator. In their case you'll need to write `template<typename,typename> class C` but if you want to use it with containers which have a different number of template parameters (let's say `std::set`), it will not work anymore.

Comment: @ViktorSehr: I edited by answer, note that `vector`/`list` take an extra parameter `allocator`, that's why I use 2 template parameters for `C`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that the way you're trying to use `C`, it isn't a simple type, but actually a class template.  You want a template-template parameter:

```
template<template<typename> class C, typename T0, typename T1>
C<T1> convert_container( C<T0> const &container, T1 value ) {
    C<T1> new_container;
    // Do some stuff...
    return new_container;
}
```

Note that this won't typically work properly with standard containers such as `vector`, since they take more than one template argument (although some of them are defaulted).  If you're working in C++11, you can do as @Jarod42 suggests and use `template<typename...>` instead of `template<typename>`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, your version looks a bit unclean. I'd rather go with this approach:

```
#include <iterator>

template <class TargetContainer, class OriginalContainer>
TargetContainer convert_container(const OriginalContainer& inputContainer)
{
    TargetContainer result;

    auto inserter = std::inserter(result, result.begin());
    for (auto& item: inputContainer) {
        *inserter = item;
    }

    return result;
}
```

..which can be used like:

```
std::vector<int> vectorOfInts {1, 2, 3, 4};

auto vectorOfFloats = convert_container<std::vector<float>>(vectorOfInts);
auto listOfDoubles  = convert_container<std::list<double>>(vectorOfFloats);
auto setOfLongsWithCustomAlocator = convert_container<std::set<long, myComparator, myAlocator>>(...); //etc
```

If you don't want to use any C++11 just replace the range based for in `convert_container` with a normal for loop and the `auto` declaration with it's proper type.